# Changing data in a extjs 4.1 store on demand

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-stores

I am using extjs 4.1 data store. I have attached the store to three grids.

When user selects a record on gridOne, I update `addedOnGridOne` property to true. Similarly when user add a record on GridTwo, I update `addedOnGridTwo` property to true.

Now I have a added a  checkbox, when this checkbox is checked, I need to reset  `addedOnGridOne` & `addedOnGridTwo` properties available in the store & while this checkbox is checked, i need to separately maintain `addedOnGridOne` & `addedOnGridTwo` properties.

What I want is: After the store is loaded for the first time, I want to create two copies of data available in store.

If the checkbox is chedked, I will load the first copy of data and if user is on tab two I will load second copy of data.

What options are available to me here? is it a good idea. Is there any better approach? Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

One store for more grids almost always leads to troubles as sorting, filtering and editing influences all three grids. If you need three grids working with the same data you could have three separate store instances loaded with the same data.

Comment: Problem is in my existing code, I have used the store directly (instead of using grid to get the store, I am requesting store using Ext.getStore() to get the store ) Now if i create multiple instance of store & attach to each grid, I will have to change the code at multiple places.

Comment: Yeah, some refactoring shall be needed. Create the store in grid's initComponent.

Comment: At this stage, I do not want to refactor the code. Is it ok to create two copies of data and load the data into the store using `loadData()` based on status of the checkbox?

Comment: Sure it's possible but if the store is used in other grids it does not solve the problem of having these grids independent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not want to make the grid independent since they use the same data and if some attribute is added on grid 1, I do not want user to add that data on grid 2. but since this new requirement has come, I need to make some adjustments.